# R: Directly Creating Tables on a Server

Tags: sql, r, database, odbc, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I run the following code:

```
library(RODBC)
library(sqldf)

con = odbcConnect("some name", uid = "some id", pwd = "abc")

sample_query = sqlQuery(con, "select distinct * from table_a a 
inner join table_b b
on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3 and a.id1 = b.id1) or a.id2 = b.id2)

view(sample_query)
```

**My Question:** Is there a way to directly place "sample_query" on to the server specified in the "con" statement? Currently, "sample_query" is being created within the global environment in R studio - but is there a way to place "sample_query" on the server (i.e. the same place where "table_a" and "table_b" are located)?

Thanks!

Comment: yes , you can make a stored procedure and execute the stored procedure from R

Comment: @ eshirvana: thank you for your reply! Can you please show me how to do this? Thanks

Comment: Stored procs are usually DBMS-specific, meaning you can't take a stored proc for (say) SQL Server and expect the same syntax to work on PostgreSQL. However, a `VIEW` should work equally well (as far as they are SQL-compatible). `CREATE VIEW myviewname AS SELECT ... FROM ...`.

Comment: @stats555, any thoughts on the provided answers? You have a recent sequence of unaccepted answers, please consider giving closure or actionable feedback for your questions with no accepted answers.

Comment: @ r2evans : thank you for your reply! I was actually able to figure out how to do what I wanted using the "odbc" and the "dbi" libraries. Would you like me to post the answer I figured out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a stored procedure in your RDBMS with your query like so (pseudocode as it can be slightly different syntax in different database engines):

```
create procedure procname 
as 
    select distinct * 
    from table_a a 
    inner join table_b b on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3 and a.id1 = b.id1) 
                         or a.id2 = b.id2)
end
```

Then :

```
library(RODBC)
library(sqldf)

con = odbcConnect("some name", uid = "some id", pwd = "abc")

sample_query = sqlQuery(con, "exec procname")

view(sample_query)
```

In some rdbms, command to call a procedure is like `call procname`.

This way you can avoid SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 1):

A SQL "VIEW" tends to be fairly compatible across DMBSes:

```sql
CREATE VIEW viewname
AS
select distinct *
from table_a a 
  inner join table_b b
  on (a.date_1 between b.date_2 and b.date_3 and a.id1 = b.id1) or a.id2 = b.id2)
```

(Often it's considered a good practice to be explicit about columns being returned, i.e., not using `*`, though this can seen as preference to many.)

With this, treat `viewname` as if it were a table, with or without a `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT * from viewname
```